# Calling a recursive function using a single Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Currently I've got a recursive function, let's call it `build_node`, which builds a binary tree. The time of computation of the function can vary, so the Thread Pool pattern is good here.

I'm wondering how can I use the `multiprocessing.Pool` in this case. The naive implementation doesn't work.

```
import time, multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

def build_node(dummy=0):
     # complex computations
     time.sleep(1)

     # exit condition
     if dummy == 3:
         return 42

     # inserting nodes
     result = {}
     for i in xrange(4):
         results[i] = pool.apply_async(build_node, [dummy + 1]).get()
     return result

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     print pool.apply_async(build_node).get()
```

The problem is that the `multiprocessing.Pool` instance `pool` needs to see definition of function `build_node` and vice versa. And I simply don't understand how to resolve this circular dependency.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410118/python-3-4-multiprocessing-recursive-pool-map

Comment: Please add the error message + traceback to your question